# R Shiny: async downloadHandler

Tags: r, asynchronous, shiny

I have a shiny app which takes a large amount of time downloading zip files. I am trying to use the `futures` and `promises` packages to manage the downloads so that other users can access the app while downloads are in progress.

The app looks as below:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  downloadButton("Download", "Download")
)


server <- function(input, output){
  output$Download <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "Downloads.zip",
    content = function(file){
      withProgress(message = "Writing Files to Disk. Please wait...", {
        temp <- setwd(tempdir())
        on.exit(setwd(temp))
        files <- c("mtcars.csv", "iris.csv")

        write.csv(mtcars, "mtcars.csv")
        write.csv(iris, "iris.csv")



        zip(zipfile = file, files = files)
      })
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I've tried wrapping the `write.csv` inside a `future` function and setting `and while this does not throw an error, the app is not available for other users during the download.

```
library(shiny)
library(promises)
library(future)
plan(multiprocess)

ui <- fluidPage(
  downloadButton("Download", "Download")
)


server <- function(input, output){
  output$Download <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "Downloads.zip",
    content = function(file){
      withProgress(message = "Writing Files to Disk. Please wait...", {
        temp <- setwd(tempdir())
        on.exit(setwd(temp))
        files <- c("mtcars.csv", "iris.csv")

        future(write.csv(mtcars, "mtcars.csv"))
        future(write.csv(iris, "iris.csv"))



        zip(zipfile = file, files = files)
      })
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I've also tried wrapping the entire `downloadHandler` function inside the `future` function, but I get the error:

> Error in .subset2(x, "impl")$defineOutput(name, value, label) :
>   Unexpected MulticoreFuture output for DownloadUnexpected
>   MultiprocessFuture output for DownloadUnexpected Future output for
>   DownloadUnexpected environment output for Download

How can I handle the entire `downloadHandler` asyncronously? I am using the open source version of shiny server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't know if you still need an answer for this, but I think you were very close. I have wrapped both the write.csv and zip in future as below and it works for multiple users on my testing.

```
library(shiny)
library(promises)
library(future)
plan(multiprocess)

ui <- fluidPage(
  downloadButton("Download", "Download")
)


server <- function(input, output){
  output$Download <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "Downloads.zip",
    content = function(file){
      withProgress(message = "Writing Files to Disk. Please wait...", {
        temp <- setwd(tempdir())
        on.exit(setwd(temp))
        files <- c("mtcars.csv", "iris.csv")

        future({

        Sys.sleep(15)  
        write.csv(mtcars, "mtcars.csv")
        write.csv(iris, "iris.csv")



        zip(zipfile = file, files = files)})
      })
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks @tigerloveslobsters. Just an additional comment that for reactive values/expressions, they must be read in advance of launching the future.