# Is it possible to change downloading behavior for large PNG files?

Tags: r, shiny

In my Shiny app, I produce a plot that is quite heavy. When I want to download this plot, R first produces the PNG file in the background and then opens the file system to choose where I want to save it.

The problem is that the plot creation takes some time after clicking on the download button, and therefore the user doesn't know if it worked.

Example below: the plot is a bit heavy so it takes some time to appear. Wait for it to appear before clicking on the "download" button.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

foo <- data.frame(
  x = sample(seq(1, 20, by = 0.01), 5*1e5, replace = TRUE),
  y = sample(seq(1, 20, by = 0.01), 5*1e5, replace = TRUE)
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  downloadButton('foo'),
  plotOutput("test")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$test <- renderPlot(ggplot(foo, aes(x, y)) + geom_point())
  output$foo = downloadHandler(
    filename = 'test.png',
    content = function(file) {
      ggsave(file)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Is there a way to invert the process, i.e first let the user choose where to save the plot and then produce the PNG in the background? I think that would provide a better user experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your comment below [@manro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70227524/9841389): promises won't help here.

They are preventing other shiny sessions from being blocked by a busy session. They increase inter-session responsiveness not intra-session responsiveness - [although there are (potentially dangerous) workarounds](https://github.com/rstudio/promises/issues/23#issuecomment-386687705).

See this answer for testing:
[R Shiny: async downloadHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53478197/r-shiny-async-downloadhandler)

In the end the `downloadButton` just provides a link (a-tag) with a [download attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html#downloading-resources).

If the linked resource does not exist when the client tries to access it the browser will throw an error (as it does when clicking the `downloadButton` before the plot is ready in your MRE).
Also the dialog to provide the file path is executed by the clients browser after clicking the link (and not by R).

I think somehow notifying the user is all you can do:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

foo <- data.frame(
  x = sample(seq(1, 20, by = 0.01), 1e5, replace = TRUE),
  y = sample(seq(1, 20, by = 0.01), 1e5, replace = TRUE)
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$br(),
  conditionalPanel(condition = 'output.test == null', tags$b("Generating plot...")),
  conditionalPanel(condition = 'output.test != null', downloadButton('foo'), style = "display: none;"),
  plotOutput("test")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$test <- renderPlot(ggplot(foo, aes(x, y)) + geom_point())
  output$foo = downloadHandler(
    filename = 'test.png',
    content = function(file) {
      showNotification(
        ui = tags$b("Preparing download..."),
        duration = NULL,
        closeButton = TRUE,
        id = "download_notification",
        type = "message",
        session = session
      )
      ggsave(file)
      removeNotification(id = "download_notification", session = session)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: result]

Comment: Ok, and I guess the browser can't open the file system before the file to save exists, right?

Comment: @bretauv exactly.

Answer (score 0):

This is my first Shiny App, so I'm sure it could be improved ;)

I think, that from the point of UX - it is better to do in the following way: **"display a graph -> save the graph"**

---

**An addition:**

So, I added a busy spinner, now an user of this app can know that this graph still rendering. You can use several styles, choose your favourite [there](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shinybusy/vignettes/shinybusy-usage.html):

---

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(shinybusy)

#your data  
df <- data.frame(
  x <- sample(seq(1, 20, by = 0.01), 5*1e5, replace = TRUE),
  y <- sample(seq(1, 20, by = 0.01), 5*1e5, replace = TRUE)
)

#your plot
plot_df <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() 

#my plot 
my_plot <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(price, fill = cut)) +
              geom_histogram(binwidth = 500)

ui <- fluidPage(
      #our buttons
      br(),
      actionButton("button1", label = "View graph"),
      br(),
      br(),
      plotOutput("button1"),
      uiOutput("button2"),
      add_busy_spinner(spin = "fading-circle")      
      )

server <- function(input, output) {
              
       observeEvent(input$button1, {
         output$button1 <- renderPlot(my_plot)
         output$button2 <- renderUI({
           br()               
           downloadButton("button3")
         })
       })
       
       output$button3 <- downloadHandler(
          filename <- 'test.png',
          content <- function(file){
                    ggsave(file)
          }
       )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes it is better to display the graph first and then to save it, but that was not the problem described in my question (or I just didn't describe it well). My problem is that I have a plot that is quite heavy (this is why it doesn't appear directly at the start of the app), and when I press on "download" after it appeared, the graph is first converted to a PNG and then downloaded. The issue is that the conversion to a PNG file takes a long time so the user doesn't see anything happening. So my question is: is there a way to choose where to save the plot before creating the PNG? I'll edit

Comment: @bretauv You can add a text label, f.e. (please, wait a moment  - plot is rendering). It will be enough, I think.

Comment: @bretauv Look to an addition ;)

Comment: Yes using a waiting indicator could work, but still I would prefer the user not having to wait for the PNG file to be created in the background. What I have in mind is to make the user choose directly where to save the file and then use [promises](https://rstudio.github.io/promises/) so that the user can continue to use the app while the PNG file is being created.

Comment: @bretauv Sorry, I can't help you with ```library(promises)```. As I said earlier, it is my first Shiny App :) I need to learn yet a lot.

Comment: Sure, thanks for your effort anyway